# How to publish the MVC 5 Default Connection Database to winHost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have no experience with web hosting. This would be my first application to host.I have an MVC 5 application with Entity Framework. It is locally using two DBs, the one that I created (BailBond) and the default one named "aspnet-BailBondMS-20160913064154" because my project name is BailBondMS. When I publish it winhost, the default DB is not connected to the application. I manually tried to create a DB in my site database in winhost with the same name but it wont let me do it because the name is too long. I then shortened the name. The problem now is that I cannot update the default DB name in Visual Studio to match the one in my control panel in winhost.
What should I do? What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Mark Spencer, Do you just place the .bak file in the App_Data folder... and the WinHost does the rest? I'm new to hosting and don't have much context to the process.  Any help is appreciated, Thank You in advance!